# How to list all users (under all domains) in an organisation?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace

Organisations can have multiple domains under their Google Apps account, and each domain can have users under it. For example, the organisation domain is `company.com`, but it also has `parkeddomain.com` associated with it (admin console -> domains).

I want to get the list of all users, both listed under `company.com` - john@company.com and `parkeddomain.com` - michael@parkeddomain.com.

I'm currently using this api call:

`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=company.com`

But it only returns users who are in the `company.com`.

Question: Is there a way to return all users from all domains? If not, is there a way to get all the domains for this organisation so that I can manually iterate over them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve all users of a company using the customer filter (customer=my_customer).

> The unique ID for the customer's Google account. In case of a multi-domain account, to fetch all groups for a customer, fill this field instead of domain. As an account administrator, you can also use the `my_customer` alias to represent your account's `customerId`. The `customerId` is also returned as part of the Users resource. Either the `customer` or the `domain` parameter must be provided.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list).